# How to switch between different data sources?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have created a blueprint, since I guess it would be easier for me to present the problem.

[image]

As seen in the blueprint, I have several sources of data, and I want to switch between the sources after I make the process only.

My code is:

```
Data_source_1=['AAA','BBB', 'CCC']
Data_source_2=['DDD','EEE', 'FFF']
Data_source_3=['GGG','HHH', 'III']

Data_source_N=['XXX','YYY', 'ZZZ']

for Data in (Data_source_1, then Data_source_2, then Data_source_3...until Data_source_N):
    ''' Do the process '''

    print (''' Print the data''')
```

How can I tell the program to switch? **I tried "for loop", but this loop repeat Data_source_1 again and again, and i am not interesting to repeat more then one time each Data_source.**
I am using python 2.7.

Comment: what's controlling your process? and based on what condition/event would you like data_source to switched?

Comment: @lv10, I collect basic stock data and make some calculations. if in the process, i  recognize some "Trues", than i ask for more data (different data from other site), and again and again until to the end.

Answer (score 1):

You can nested if statement within your loop which when true will trigger other databases.

```
for Data in (Data_source_1):
''' Do the process '''
 if something True:
   for Data in (Data_source_2):
      ''' Do the process '''
```

And so on.

You can also run a `while True:` loop which runs continuously and within that you can have multiple if conditions which when satisfied will trigger your data_source_n

```
while True:
if something is True:
    hit data_source_1
if something is True:
    hit data_source_2
```

Hope this helps your case.

Comment: If the answer helped please accept it and upvote it. Thanks in Advance! :)

Comment: I see some improvement. it look like good direction...i need to make some adjustments...Thanks!

Comment: Does anyone have an idea? Thanks.